# Theres a free software that runs in the browser which can be used to learn math?

Tags: math

Good afternoon.

I am looking for a free software to learn mathmatics, do some draws in R² plane and get some results, in a didatic way. Preferably that runs in the browser.

Do you know some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### GeoGebra

[GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) can help you learn about math with their [materials site](https://www.geogebra.org/materials) as well as plot in both [2D](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator) and [3D](https://www.geogebra.org/3d). It also has a [scientific calculator](https://www.geogebra.org/scientific).

All of GeoGebra can be run in the Browser. Some of it can also be run in their [offline apps](https://www.geogebra.org/download).

### Desmos

[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com) is somewhat similar to GeoGebra but can only plot in 2D. It is also mostly aimed at teachers and their students to use in the classroom.